# Any prime ideal of $R[x]$ properly containing $M[x]$ is a maximal ideal of $R[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> Let $M$ be a maximal ideal in a ring $R$. Prove that any prime ideal of $R[x]$ properly containing $M[x]$ is a maximal ideal of $R[x]$.

Help me some hints

Comment: Any thoughts or attempts?

Comment: This post maybe helpfull http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182297/maximal-ideals-in-rx

Comment: Help me. Please

Comment: you yourself has posted some link saying it may be helpful... so every one may be in a feel that you have solved it by your own... ok.. let us do it now... what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{k}$ be the residue field $R/M$.

Is an easy exercise to prove that $$ \frac{R[x]}{M[x]} \simeq \frac{R}{M} [x]= \mathbb{k}[x]$$

Recall that $\mathbb{k}[x]$ is a PID and then every non zero prime is maximal.

Now you can conclude observing that $P \subset \frac{R}{M} [x]$ is a non zero prime ideal if and only if is the projection of a prime $Q \subset R[x]$ such that $M[x] \subsetneq Q$.